# Looping through items of a combobox

Tags: c#, loops, combobox, foreach

I need to compare each item of a combobox with words of a string.
If it matches,I need to put a $ in front and at the end of the word of the string.

I tried like

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(modify))
            { 
                foreach(string item in tcomboBox1.Items) 
                {
                    bool contains = Regex.IsMatch(modify, @"\b"+item+"\b");
                    if (contains == true)
                    {
                        string theItem = "$" + item + "$";
                        modify = modify.Replace(item,theItem);
                    }
                }

                ttextBox1.Text = modify;
                modify = "";
            }
```

But the $ sign is not appended.Why so ?

Comment: You want to modify the items in combobox or what?

Comment: modify combobox items or need to show result in  `ttextBox1.Text` ? Show me example of combobox items and your expected result !

Comment: do you need to propagate changes to combobox?

Comment: @GuruStron , No the change has only to be seen in z textbox.

Comment: @zey , combobox item - TotalPresent ,modify(varies) - TotalPresent+6*8+(TotalPresent+9) ,expected result -$TotalPresent$+6*8+($TotalPresent$+9)

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn use just `if(contains)` not `if (contains == true)`

Comment: @GuruStron , solved my issue it was the Regex that was preventing the program to get INTO the loop.Thanks.

Comment: @GuruStron , I have a problem with this apporach.
I had a string as TotalInternalCalls+1.Thus I expected to get $TotalInternalCalls$+1.But,
Im my combobox I have InternalCalls as well as TotalInternalCalls so as you have guessed I got a very wrong output($InternalCalls$+1$TotalInternalCalls$+1), What may I do to rectify the above situation ?

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn try `bool contains = Regex.IsMatch(modify, @"\b"+item+@"\b");`

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn in your original regex you missed `@` before the second `"\b"`

Comment: @GuruStron .Great Thnx again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

your code was just right, based on given examples of input and results problem is in your regex, it seems that you don't need `"\b"` try just:

```
bool contains = Regex.IsMatch(modify,item);
```

Comment: my IDE is not recognising Environment.NewLine. What reference do I need to add ?

Comment: it's from [`System`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: problem inyour Regex, i think, try to use your code with `bool contains = Regex.IsMatch(modify, item);` Have you tried to step through it with debugger

Answer (score 1):

You regex expression is not correct, it does not return true if item is found anywhere inside modify string (I suppose this is what you want)

You don't need \b in prefix or suffix to match in between

```
Regex.IsMatch(modify, item);
```

This matches perfectly any text inside modify and than it should work fine